# Micro controller capable of target tracking

Tags: arduino, ip-camera

I am a high school student with limited knowledge about camera processing and i want to learn. My question is, what micro controller would be the best to use along side an ip camera to track an illuminated rectangle target(Green LED ring around camera), also are there any references to help me as i will need a guide. I have an arduino uno but i have been told that it doesn't have enough memory.

Comment: Worry about getting a computer to track first, *then* figure out how to reduce it.

Comment: I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: Then you're nowhere near ready to put it on an Arduino.

Comment: Use OpenCV and whatever platforms it supports. At this point, an Android phone is really all you need, and is cheaper/simpler to code for than a microcontroller platform. http://opencv.org/

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I have tried to use OpenCV for Java but it would make more sense to do it in c++ first.

Comment: Tracking, well anything, in an image is NOT an easy task. There is a reason that these libraries are so coveted. I would first study OCR technologies and see how they function. It will give you a blanket idea on what you need to determine shapes, colors, and lines in an image. Once you can successfully find something in an image THEN worry about tracking it. Finally, once you can track something in a video you are ready to pump it onto an arduino which, in my experience is a whoooole nother animal. Good luck youngly, keep hacking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For basic recognizon, you can use an arduino uno or similar in conjuction with a mouse sensor.
Mouse sensor are basically 36x36 pixel, black and white camera. see http://hackteria.org/wiki/index.php/Hacked_Optical_Mouse